# Can't access controller properties in view with UI router and 'controller as' syntax

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using ui-router for my routing, and am going to be using nested scopes and therefore want to be using the 'controller as' syntax. However, I can't work out the correct syntax / combinations to access the controller object properties in my view.

**`app.js (sets up routing)`**

```
(function() {

    angular

    .module('ICP_App', ['ui.router', 'satellizer', 'ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'xeditable'])

        .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $authProvider) {

            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('dashboard');

            $stateProvider
                .state('clients', {
                    url: '/clients',
                    templateUrl: '../partials/clients-index.html',
                    controller: 'ClientsController as ClientsCtrl'
            })
            // more routes here...

})();
```

**`ClientsController.js`**

```
(function() {

    angular.module('ICP_App')
        .controller('ClientsController', function($http) {
            $http.get('http://api.icp.sic.com/clients')
                .success(function(clients) {
                    var vm = this;
                    vm.clients = clients.data;
                    console.log(vm.clients);
                })
                .error(function(error) {
                    // handle here
                })
        });

})();
```

**`index.html`**

```
<body ng-app="ICP_App" ng-cloak>

<!-- sidebar, header etc -->

    <div ui-view></div> <!-- pull in view -->

</body>
```

Finally, **`clients-index.html`** partial

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="pane" ng-repeat="client in clients">
        {{ client.name }}
    </div>
</div>
```

I have also tried `client in vm.clients`, to no avail.

Is there a problem with my controller as syntax? As I am using controller as in my ui-router code, yet not again when creating my controller. If I use controller as again in my controller, it errors (`Argument ClientsController is not a`).

I should point out that console logging vm.clients does give me the data in the console, I just can't seem to access it in my view.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your ClientsController as follow

```
(function() {

angular.module('ICP_App')
    .controller('ClientsController', function($http) {
        var vm=this;
        $http.get('http://api.icp.sic.com/clients')
            .success(function(clients) {                   
                vm.clients = clients.data;
                console.log(vm.clients);
            })
            .error(function(error) {
                // handle here
            })
    }); })();
```

Modify client-index.html as following

```
<div class="content">
<div class="pane" ng-repeat="client in ClientsCtrl.clients">
    {{ client.name }}
</div>
```

Below link will help you to understand controller as syntax more deeply

https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/